# Jquery ajax Check if there results are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to pull in data from my database and plot points with google maps. What I want to do is something like, "if response=null, alert('empty')" but everytime I try to work that into this code, something just breaks. If anyone could offer any help that would be awesome. 
 Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ()

{
    var radius3 = localStorage.getItem("radius2");
    var lat3 = localStorage.getItem("lat2");
    var long3 = localStorage.getItem("long2");
    var type2 = localStorage.getItem("type2");
    var citya = localStorage.getItem("city2");
    var rep2 = localStorage.getItem("rep2");
    var size2 = localStorage.getItem("size2");
    var status2 = localStorage.getItem("status2");


    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://examplecom/test/www/base_search.php',
        data: "city2=" + city2 + "&rep2=" + rep2 + "&status2=" + status2 + "&size2=" + size2 + "&type2=" + type2 + "&long2=" + long2 + "&lat2=" + lat2 + "&radius2=" + radius2,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {


                    var lng = val['lng'];
                    var lat = val['lat'];
                    var id = val['id'];
                    var name = val['name'];
                    var address = val['address'];
                    var category = val['category'];
                    var city = val['city'];
                    var state = val['state'];
                    var rep = val['rep'];
                    var status = val['status'];
                    var size = val['size'];
                    $('div#google-map').gmap('addMarker', {
                        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                        'bounds': true,
                        'icon': 'images/hospital.png'
                    }).click(function () {
                        $('div#google-map').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                            'backgroundColor': "rgb(32,32,32)",
                            'content': "<table><tr><td>Name:</td><td>" + name + "</td></tr><tr><td>Address:</td><td>" + address + ", " + city + "&nbsp;" + state + "</td></tr><tr><td>Category:</td><td>" + category + "</td></tr><tr><td>Rep:</td><td>" + rep + "</td></tr><tr><td>Status:</td><td>" + status + "</td></tr><tr><td>Size:</td><td>" + size + "</td></tr></table>"
                        }, this);


                    });
                } else {
                    alert('hello');
                }
                }
            })

    }
    });


})
}



</script>
```

Comment: where are you putting the `if (data)`?

Comment: sorry i just updated the code above, i posted the revised code above

Comment: Is it working? there are some nesting errors in the end of the script

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like

```
success: function (data) {
    if(!data) {
        alert('empty');
        return;
    }
    $.each(data, function (key, val) { ...
```

should work.

Comment: @Nic - I wonder how did this worked if my answer didn't worked for you.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli I really don't know, I nearly deleted my answer when I saw you posted basically the exact same thing! But glad it helped :-)

Comment: @Ben I just tried this if condition to check if my AJAX response is empty but i'm not being alerted. In developer tool network XHR i see the AJAX call and there is not a single character in my response, it's empty. Any idea why the condition wouldn't work?

Comment: try sticking an alert, console.log or breakpoint before the if to see if it's hitting the success function at all.  It may be that it's actually hitting the error function of the HTTP status code is not 200.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this!

```
success: function (data) {
if(data.length == 0) {
    alert('empty');
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
       success: function (data) {
           if(data){
               //do your stuff here
           }
           else{
               alert('empty');
           }

        }
```

Comment: So i tried this, and it didn't seem to work, I posted my revised code above